# ¿Cómo puedo colocar el símbolo de porcentaje (%) a una celda en Excel por medio de PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Si tengo un número (que es el resultado de sacar un porcentaje), y quiero mostrarlo como un porciento en una celda de `Excel` por medio de la librería de `PHP` **PHPExcel** ¿Cómo puedo darle dicho formato?

Ejemplo: `12 -> 12%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()->applyFromArray( 
        array( 
            'code' => PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
        )
    );
```

Comment: no funcionó, me formatea el dato de esta manera:
12 -> 1200,00%y yo deseo que aparezca así:

Comment: Te lo formatea de esa manera ya que excel toma los % en base a 1 no a 100, si tu en excel quieres poner 12% tienes que escribir en la celda 0.12 y formatear como porcentaje